# salts affecting the salinity of water

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry

I know there are different types of salts like Himalayan salts table salts etc. I was wonder do different types of salts have a different level in salinity when dissolved in water.

Answer (score 1):

Table salt is obtained from various sources from mines and seas. The world's second largest salt mine (Khewara salt mine) is in Pakistan and this is where this so-called Himalayan pink salt originates. All of it is mostly sodium chloride however it appears pinkish because of iron impurities. If you dissolve it in water, a very small amount of brown precipitate can be seen which is mostly iron oxides.

There is no dedicated study which shows which salt is better for health or not. Himalayan pink salt has recently become a craze in gourmet (cooking) world and among the pseudo-medical sciences which claim that this pink salt contains 99 minerals and it can cure everything.

> wonder do different types of salts have a different level in salinity when dissolved in water.

You cannot quantify your personal taste for salinity. As chemists, we only care how much sodium chloride is there by mass percentage. Whatever table salt ends up in grocery stores is highly refined and purified. Grocery store salts contain small amounts of additives such as potassium iodide, potassium iodate, silicates, prussiates, thiosulfate, and so on. So the taste may be slightly different from brand to brand.